# grunt sass task producing errors due to bourbon package

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bourbon, grunt-contrib-sass

I am writing a grunt task file for my project. I have defined the `sass` task in that and installed all the required dependencies. I am able to run the same gruntfile on my friends computer, but on my computer the sass task produces this error.

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "      webkit-image": expected ")", was ": -webkit- + $p..."
        on line 21 of /home/chitrank/Documents/shaastr/frontend/frontend/frontend/app/minovate/bower_components/bourbon/dist/helpers/_linear-angle-parser.scss
        from line 10 of /home/chitrank/Documents/shaastr/frontend/frontend/frontend/app/minovate/bower_components/bourbon/dist/_bourbon.scss
        from line 6 of app/sass/main.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Due to this error I am not able to perform sass task and need to do it on my friend's computer. I am also adding my Gruntfile.js for better overview  of what my grunt tasks are and how it is working, please have a look.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);


  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);


  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
// Project settings
yeoman: appConfig,

// Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  styles: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/sass/{,*/}*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass', 'newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/tmpl/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},

// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
},

// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
},

// compile sass files
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/sass',
      src: ['*.scss'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
      ext: '.css'
    }],

    options: {
      loadPath: [
        './bower_components/bourbon/dist'
      ]
    }
  }
},

// Empties folders to start fresh
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},

// Add vendor prefixed styles
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 1 version']
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  }
},

// Automatically inject Bower components into the app
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  }
},

// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},

// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,**/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  json: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/jsons/*.json'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
},

// The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
// By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
// minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
// to use the Usemin blocks.
// cssmin: {
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
//         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
//       ]
//     }
//   }
// },
// uglify: {
//   options: {
//    mangle: { except: ["$super"] }
//   }
//   dist: {
//     files: {
//       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//       ]
//     }
//   },
// },
// concat: {
//   dist: {}
// },

uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: { except: ['$super'] }
  }
},

imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

svgmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/}*.svg',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
},

htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: false,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html', 'views/tmpl/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},

// ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
// using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
// things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
ngmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      src: '*.js',
      dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
    }]
  }
},

// Replace Google CDN references
cdnify: {
  dist: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
  }
},

// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        '*.html',
        'views/**/*',
        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
        'fonts/*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      src: ['generated/*']
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
      src: 'fonts/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/simple-line-icons',
      src: 'fonts/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
      src: 'fonts/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'bower_components/weather-icons',
      src: 'font/*',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
      src: ['jsons/**','modules/**','vendor/**'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
},

// Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
concurrent: {
  server: [
    'copy:styles'
  ],
  test: [
    'copy:styles'
  ],
  dist: [
    'copy:styles',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin'
  ]
},

// Test settings
karma: {
  unit: {
    configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }
},

// grunt-text-replace

replace: {
  html_js_css_images_rep: {
    src: ['dist/scripts/*.js', 
    'dist/styles/*.css',
    'dist/*.html',
    'dist/views/*.html' ,
    'dist/views/tmpl/*.html' ,
    'dist/views/tmpl/forms/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/layouts/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/mail/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/maps/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/pages/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/shop/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/tables/*.html',
    'dist/views/tmpl/ui/*.html'
    ],
    //dest: ['dist/scripts/'],
    overwrite: true,
    replacements: [{
      from: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
      to: ''
    },
    {
      from: 'http://localhost:8000',
      to: ''
    },
    {
      from: 'views/',
      to: 'static/views/'
    },
    {
      from: 'scripts/',
      to: 'static/scripts/'
    },
    {
      from: 'styles/',
      to: 'static/styles/'
    },
    {
      from: 'images/',
      to: 'static/images/'
    }]
  }


}




 });



// adding the text replace grunt plugin 
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');



  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'concurrent:server',
  'sass',
  'autoprefixer',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);


});



grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'sass',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin',
    'replace'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

If anyone has resolved this problem before please let me know.

Comment: This is a problem with your sass file, not grunt. Make sure that your sass is free from errors

Comment: Ahmad Alfy , the file named main.scss has @import bourbon on line no 6. So when the main.scss tries to import bourbon it imports _linear_angle_parser.scss and on line 21 webkit-image: -webkit- + $prefix + ($offset - $num) + $suffix is stated. Therefore it is clear that something is wrong with bourbon package only and since my friend is running it successfully on his computer so it should work on my system too.

Answer (score 1):

[This discussion](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/419) says that this issue is caused by incompatibility between the versions of Sass and Bourbon.

Bourbon 4 require at least Sass 3.3 so if you are running a lower version you need to either downgrade Bourbon to 3.x or upgrade Sass

Comment: I have checked my bourbon and sass version. So bourbon is 4.2.3 and sass is 3.4.14 and bourbon node package I am using is 4.0.2.